# How to get the coordinates for rotated axes?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, coordinate-systems, vectors

I'm  quoting from the Feynman Lectures:

> "Assume that Moe’s axes have rotated relative to Joe’s by an angle θ. The two coordinate systems are shown in Fig. 11-2, which is restricted to two dimensions. Consider any point P having coordinates (x, y) in Joe’s
> system and (x′, y′) in Moe’s system. We shall begin, as in the previous case, by
> expressing the coordinates x′ and y′ in terms of x, y, and θ. To do so, we first
> drop perpendiculars from P to all four axes and draw AB perpendicular to PQ.
> Inspection of the figure shows that x′ can be written as the sum of two lengths
> along the x′-axis, and y′ as the difference of two lengths along AB. All these
> 11-3
> lengths are expressed in terms of x, y, and θ in equations (11.5), to which we
> have added an equation for the third dimension.
> x′ = x cos θ + y sin θ,
> y′ = y cos θ − x sin θ,
> z′ = z."
> Here is the figure:

[image]

How to prove x′ = x cos θ + y sin θ & y′ = y cos θ − x sin θ?

Comment: with geometry and similarity of triangles

Comment: Link to Feynman Lectures webpage?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

> How to prove x′ = x cos θ + y sin θ & y′ = y cos θ − x sin θ

from the  two  red rectangle triangles , you can see the results